# Must edit routes.rb after starting server for routes to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree, webrick

I am starting WEBrick with `rails -s`

After the server starts, none of my routes work until I make a small edit to `routes.rb` - eg just add a blank line and save again.  Note I do not restart the server after this edit.

I don't have the same problem in production, which is using Apache instead of WEBrick.

I'm using Rails 4.0.5 and Spree 2.2.2

Comment: So you're saying that your routes files is not readed by the rails application on starting the server but it does after you save the changes. Are you using git?

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos yes, that's correct. The routes do not seem to be read when the server is started, but making any edit to routes.rb and saving the file fixes the issue. Yes, using git. I don't see how that's relevant in this case

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird sounding error. I've never seen this happen in several years of using Rails. I guess the first thing I would try doing is switching from Webrick to something else, like thin.

Try adding thin to your Gemfile, then run `thin start -p 3000` or whatever and see if this persists.